# Draw two bikes (tronlight) with two different color in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to draw two bikes for the game tronlightbikes
with two different colors in the same canvas but it seems that I'm missing something in the function redraw() (I'm a newbie in javascript).

```
var redraw = function() {
C.fillStyle = "#000000";
// C.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
C.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

C.fillStyle = 'red';

for ( var i = 0; i < NUM_CELLS_HORIZONTAL; ++i ) {
    for ( var j = 0; j < NUM_CELLS_VERTICAL; ++j ) {
        if ( grid[i][j] === CELL_OCCUPIED )

        C.fillRect( x0+i*cellSize+1, y0+j*cellSize+1, cellSize-2, cellSize-2 );     
    }
}

C.fillStyle = lightCycle1_alive ? "#ff0000" : "#ffffff";
C.fillRect( x0+lightCycle1_x*cellSize, y0+lightCycle1_y*cellSize, cellSize, cellSize );
C2.fillStyle = lightCycle2_alive ? "#ff0000" : "#ffffff";
C2.fillRect( x0+lightCycle2_x*cellSize, y0+lightCycle2_y*cellSize, cellSize, cellSize );

}
```

Comment: so specify what is the problem and your question?

Comment: what exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]*.

Comment: actually the trails are in one color (red) i wanna make a trail color for each bike, one red and one green.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fillStyle property of the canvas to set color. I believe you just need to change the fillStyle as needed before calling fillRect.

Comment: the fill rect inside de loop  sets the color for both bikes (the trail). do you have any idea how can i set different colors for the trails ?

Comment: It looks like the grid only keeps track of occupied cells. Not necessarily which bike trail is occupying the cell. You'd need to distinguish which bike created the trail by tracing the occupied cells back to the origin bike. Or when populating this grid object store which bike is creating the trail.